# In VS Code how to change the file name in all linked files

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, plugins

In VSCODE I want that when I rename some file from explorer, it should change the file name in all linked files.

For example if I change my styles_xyz.css to style.css it should change the name in all html files like this `<link href="css/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`
I know I can change it later with `CTRL + SHIFT + F` But I want this change automatically.

Comment: if you can't find an extension that does the trick why not write it yourself and let us also benefit by putting it in the Marketplace

Comment: @rioV8 Its a good recommendation, I never did it before, But will try to do it.